# Group By but specify number of rows per grouped id

Tags: mysql

I have the following:

```
id | name  | Book Read        | Date Read
1    Maria   Dogs love cats     12/31/2008
1    Maria   Cats and Dogs      12/31/2007
1    Maria   Cowboys            12/31/2006
2    Tom     Cowboys            12/31/2008
2    Tom     Indians            12/31/2005
2    Tom     Cats and Dogs      12/31/2003
3    Harry   Raining hard       12/31/2005
3    Harry   Cats and Dogs      12/31/2002
3    Harry   Indians            12/31/2001
```

If I do "SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id", I get:

```
id | name  | Book Read         | Date Read
1    Maria   Dogs love cats      12/31/2008
2    Tom     Cowboys             12/31/2008
3    Harry   Raining hard        12/31/2005
```

But how do I get the first 2 books for each person? i.e.:

```
id | name  | Book Read         | Date Read
1    Maria   Dogs love cats      12/31/2008
1    Maria   Cats and Dogs       12/31/2007
2    Tom     Cowboys             12/31/2008
2    Tom     Indians             12/31/2005
3    Harry   Raining hard        12/31/2005
3    Harry   Cats and Dogs       12/31/2002
```

Comment: The SQL will be very long, ugly and unreadable. I think the better option is to get all data and to process them in an external language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have an autoincrement field, in my example called i

```
select * from table as t1
where (select count(*) from table as t2
       where t1.id = t2.id and t2.i < t1.i) <2
```

This is another alternative

```
select tmp.i,tmp.id,tmp.name,tmp.book_read
from (
  select 
    id,i,name,book_read,
    if( @prev <> id, @r:=1,@r:=@r+1 ) as rank,
    @prev := id
  from table as t
  join (select @r:=null,@prev:=0) as rn
  order by t.id,t.i
) as tmp
where tmp.rank <= 2
order by i,id;
```

Comment: I think you lost me on the autoincrement field. How do I do it with the fields I have in my example?

Comment: if you don't have an autoincrement field how can you specify two records per group?

Comment: I laid it out my example above. I don't have an autoincrement field above